# Script : substitute value in script and display it

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have this sql command : insert into `users`(`username`, `password`) values ($username, $password)

I want to display this line for every user

this is my script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for name in $(cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1)
    do
    pass= sudo grep -w $name /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2

    echo 'insert into `users`(`username`, `password`) values ($name, $pass)'
    done
```

But when i execute the script it doesn't do the substitution

Comment: One of several problems with your script is: There is no parameter expansion (I think this is what you mean by _substitution_) going on in your `echo` line, because you used singled quotes around the argument to echo, and single quotes tell bash to **not** expand the parameter `$name` and $pass`. Another one is that you never set the variable `pass` (this is due to the incorrect space after the equal sign). Finally, the backquotes around _users_ etc. don't make sense.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.

Answer (score 2):

As root (`sudo -s`):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read name; do
    pass=$(grep -w "$name" /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2)
    echo "INSERT INTO \`users\`(\`username\`, \`password\`) VALUES ($name, $pass)"
done < <(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd)
```

### Notes

---

If you are a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) beginniner, some good pointers to start learning :

[FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ),
[Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide),
[Ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html),
[bash hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/),
[quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), 
[Check your script](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

And avoid people recommendations saying to learn with tldp.org web site, the tldp bash guide -ABS in particular) is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong. The [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and the [bash-hackers' wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Activate_Bash.27s_Debug_Mode) are far more reliable.

---

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Another good pointer for beginners (and others) is to use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find problems.

Comment: Gilles Quenot, sorry I missed your link to [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).  I also recommend the [Stack Overflow 'bash' Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) as a useful learning resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have fixed the issues with your script. Please check if it works now :

```
#!/bin/bash
while read name
do 
    pass=$( sudo grep -w $name /etc/shadow | awk -F':' '{print $2}' )
    echo "insert into 'users'('username', 'password') values ($name, $pass)"
done <<< "$(awk -F':' '{print $1}' /etc/passwd))"
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code, which needs to be run as root:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

while IFS=: read -r name pass _ ; do
    printf "insert into users (username, password) values ('%s', '%s')\\n" \
            "$name" "$pass"
done </etc/shadow
```

- `/etc/shadow` should contain the same users as `/etc/passwd`, so the code doesn't use `/etc/passwd`.
- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of how `while IFS=: read -r ...` works.  It also explains the use of `_` as a "junk variable".
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why the code uses `printf` instead of `echo`.